# Animating the centering of a div

Tags: javascript, css, animation, center

How do I animate this movement so when I call the function later the item will animate? I usually use `$(this).animate` but not sure how to wrap this in it, since I'm calculating its position. Thanks.

```
jQuery.fn.center = function ()
{
    this.css("position","absolute");
    this.css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2) + 
        $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
    this.css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $(this).outerWidth()) / 2) + 
        $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
    return this;
}
```

Comment: i just get that you are centering the element but what about animation  is not clear to me ..

Comment: see my answer i have added [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mAA6U/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `this.css` you can use `this.animate` as you mentioned.

**Example**

```
this.animate({ 
  top : Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight()) / 2) + 
        $(window).scrollTop()) + "px"
},800,function(){  });
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mAA6U/1/)

Answer (score 0):

To animate, you'll need to use animate on the left/top values, but first set the position to absolute using `css()`.

```
        // can't easily animate change of css "position"
        // so we just set it directly
        elt.css('position', 'absolute');

        // animate the position
        elt.animate({
            left: x,
            top: y
        });
```

I created a fiddle for this, here: http://jsfiddle.net/lingo/CkRUd/2/

In the fiddle I've also tidied some things up to make sure the plugin is more robust.

Comment: Luke, thanks a bunch! This worked pretty great. I added a .stop()animate because I wanted the animation to go back and forth depending on hover on and off.  The only problem is the animated box starts out centered at the top of the screen, and when I use your code, it makes the animation start at the top left...How do I make the animation start with the objects original coordinates?  It's literally only during the first cycle of the animation it starts at the top left then moves center screen. So strange. Thanks! I assume it's because the x and y are starting at 0.

Comment: That's right.  If the object is positioned 'absolute', then the left&top values will be relative to the screen (or to the first position:relative ancestor), and so it won't be centered.

The trick to this is to copy in the object's current position at the same time as setting position=absolute.

See the same fiddle as before, on lines 23 on and you'll see that I get the element position via `offset()` and copy it in to the CSS.